# How do I make the like counter to go down when I click the dislike button and vice versa?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, voting, vote, vote-up-buttons

this is the controller with like action:

```
 def like
like = Like.create(like: params[:like], user: current_user, story: @story)

respond_to do|format|
  if like.valid?
    format.js
  else
    format.js {render status: 403, js: "alert('You can only like/dislike a story once')"}
  end
end
```

this is the model that has the counter from model:

```
   def thumbs_up_total
       self.likes.where(like: true).size
   end

   def thumbs_down_total
       self.likes.where(like: false).size
   end
```

this is the View. I am getting the counter from the model. 'thumbs up' and 'thumbs down':

```
          <div class="pull-right">
              <%= link_to like_story_path(story, like: true), method: :post, data: { remote: true } do %>
              <div class="likes"></div>
              <% end %>
              <div id = "like-<%= story.id %>">
              <%= story.thumbs_up_total %>
              </div>
              <%= link_to like_story_path(story, like: false), method: :post, data: { remote: true } do %>
              <div class="dislikes"></div>
              <% end %>
              <div id="dislike-<%= story.id %>">
              <%= story.thumbs_down_total %>
              </div>
           </div>
```

Comment: this action only creates new like correct? Can you show the view action where you actually displaying the story

Comment: hello Ilia, i have updated the post. please let me know. thanks!

Comment: Which controller action is triggered when you click on the link? Can you post the log generated upon clicking the link?

Comment: hi Pavan, the 'like' action in the stories controller gets triggered.

Comment: <%= story.thumbs_up_total %> try substituting this line with <%= story.thumbs_up_total - story.thumbs_down_total%>

Comment: Thanks Ilia. I would like to make the dislike button do the same. so if a dislike button clicked, a like counter goes down.. if a like button clicked, then a dislike counter goes down.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are asking for something like this, correct?

```
<div class="pull-right">
              <%= link_to like_story_path(story, like: true), method: :post, data: { remote: true } do %>
              <div class="likes"></div>
              <% end %>
              <div id = "like-<%= story.id %>">
              <%= story.thumbs_up_total - story.thumbs_down_total%>
              </div>
              <%= link_to like_story_path(story, like: false), method: :post, data: { remote: true } do %>
              <div class="dislikes"></div>
              <% end %>
              <div id="dislike-<%= story.id %>">
              <%= story.thumbs_down_total - story.thumbs_up_total %>
              </div>
           </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move parts of your view to partials, create`like.js` and fill it with code to render the partials.

First change your view code to this

```
      <div class="pull-right">
          <%= link_to like_story_path(story, like: true), method: :post, data: { remote: true } do %>
          <div class="likes"></div>
          <% end %>
          <%= render "thumbs_up" %>
          <%= link_to like_story_path(story, like: false), method: :post, data: { remote: true } do %>
          <div class="dislikes"></div>
          <% end %>
          <%= render "thumbs_down" %>>
       </div>
```

Then create two new partials.

```
# _thumbs_up.html..erb
<div id = "like-<%= story.id %>" class="thumbs-up">
     <%= story.thumbs_up_total %>
 </div>

# _thumbs_down.html..erb
<div id = "like-<%= story.id %>" class="thumbs-down">
     <%= story.thumbs_down_total %>
 </div>
```

Add a file called `like.js`

```
# like.js
$(".thumbs-up").html("<%= j(render("thumbs_up")) %>");
$(".thumbs-down").html("<%= j(render("thumbs_down")) %>");
```

like.js will then be called when your links are clicked. It will re-render your partials and update your thumb counts on click.